# Removing a fragment after adding does not work

Tags: android, android-fragments, checkbox, fragment

My problem is that I want to remove a `Fragment` from an Activity. There are two steps:

1. Adding the `Fragment` into a `FrameLayout` (R.id.frame_for_des_details) by checking the `CheckBox`.
2. Removing the `Fragment` by clicking a `TextView`

   ```
   public class CreateTripActivity extends FragmentActivity {

   //Vars for Destination Fragment
   private CheckBox checkBox;
   private DestinationDetailsFragment destinationDetailsFragment;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   //Setting the ContentView
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_trip);

   //Set the Destination Checkbox listener
   checkBox = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_destination_now);
   ```

Listener for the `CheckBox`:

```
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

            //Adding the Fragment. THIS WORK
            destinationDetailsFragment = new DestinationDetailsFragment();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_for_des_details, destinationDetailsFragment).commit();

        }
    });
```

Listener for the `TextView`:

```
    findViewById(R.id.label_later).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //Removing the Fragment. DOES NOT WORK
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction().remove(destinationDetailsFragment).commit();              
        }
    });

    }
```

When I check the `CheckBox`, I can see the Fragment. But when I click the `TextView` to remove it, it remains.
When I check the `CheckBox` again and again it seems that the new `Fragment` overlays the older fragment so I can write over placeholders in an `EditText`.

I hope someone understand me and can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked if your textview's onClick is actually fired? To be sure, you can print a log inside that method to see whether it reached there. BTW, it's not a good idea to use onClicklistener of a TextView to remove a fragment.

Comment: @elvisrusu support fragment manager needs to be used if someone uses  `Fragment` from the support library. `android.app.Fragment` and `android.support.v*.Fragment` are two different beasts. You cannot mix these two things up.

Comment: Try adding `android:clickable="true"` to the TextView

Answer (score 0):

Try The android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager. Here is the code.

```
        destinationDetailsFragment = new DestinationDetailsFragment();
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton,
                boolean b) {

            // Adding the Fragment. THIS WORK

            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.frame_for_des_details,
                            destinationDetailsFragment).commit();

        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.label_later).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fm.beginTransaction()
                            .remove(destinationDetailsFragment).commit();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

FIXED

I implement a the Fragment as android.support.v4.app.Fragment but that wasnt the problem.

Before I add the fragment i removed the checkbox. And bevor removing the Fragment i add the checkbox again to the View. But i also called checkbox.setChecked(false). That fired the onCheckedChanged again!

My new Code

```
@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_destination);
                //Remove and Add Content
                layout.removeView(checkBox);

                destinationDetailsFragment = new DestinationDetailsFragment();
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_for_des_details, destinationDetailsFragment).commit();

                //Enable Later Button
                findViewById(R.id.img_later).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.label_later).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
```

Thanks.